# MSBuild Command Line arguments length exceeds 8191 characters

Tags: msbuild

I are using MSBUILD.exe to perform build for the application. as part of this I pass the required variables as command line arguments for MSBUILD.exe.

I have 2 files. service.xml and MyService.proj. Below line is present in service.xml file.

```
<installCommand name="MyService" cmd="msbuild.exe &quot;MyService.proj&quot; /p:{vairables}">
```

initially the length of the command was small and everything was fine as I was able to build my project but as the project size increased the number of parameters also increased, and now I am at a stage where the command line is displaying an error (Input line is too Long).

Upon some searching I found out that command line cannot be more than 8191 characters.

Can any one Suggest any alternatives for this.

Answer (score 0):

What's `installCommand`?

MSBuild engine merges all system, user and process variables as well as parameters and properties into one big pool, so every property that you pass via `{vairables}` can be `set` first separatly. Keep in mind that properties pass via command line are **global** properties so environment variable equivalent will not override corresponding project property unless it has `Condition=" '$(Foo)' == '' "` on it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx

Comment: Thank you for you Comment I have edited the original Post. Yes the variables are first set and then passed to the command for execution. The variables that I am passing are exceeding the max length allowed.

Comment: @RaghavendraPrasad My point is, if you `set` them first, i.e. make `{vairables}` into environment variables than you don't need to pass them to `/p:` anymore, MSBuild will read them anyway hence command line will be minimal.

Comment: Ilya Kozhevnikov:  I tried to assign my variables to environment variables. I used this as my reference. [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0fb8d97d-513e-4d37-8528-52973f65a034/how-to-set-envrionment-variables-in-msbuild-file?forum=msbuild] But I was not successful with this in achieving my goal. Can you provide any sample or Point to a reference of creating environment variables in build XML file.

Answer (score 0):

You can set variables in an xml file, and pass the xml file-name to the msbuild script.

Here is a simple example that uses the MSBuildCommunityTasks.

Parameters.xml (contents below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters>
  <setParameter name="LineNumber1" value="PeanutsAreCool" />
  <setParameter name="LineNumber2" value="" />
</parameters>
```

MyMsbuildDef.proj (contents below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project  ToolsVersion="4.0"  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="AllTargetsWrapped">

    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />



    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- Always declare some kind of "base directory" and then work off of that in the majority of cases  -->
        <WorkingCheckout>.</WorkingCheckout>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="AllTargetsWrapped">
        <CallTarget Targets="ReadXmlPeekValue" />
        <CallTarget Targets="WriteXmlPeekValue" />
    </Target>   


    <Target Name="ReadXmlPeekValue">
        <!-- you do not need a namespace for this example, but I left it in for future reference -->
        <XmlPeek Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='peanutNamespace' Uri='http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'/&gt;"
             XmlInputPath=".\Parameters.xml" 
             Query="/parameters/setParameter[@name='LineNumber1']/@value">
            <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="Peeked" />
        </XmlPeek>

        <Message Text="@(Peeked)"/>

        <XmlPeek Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='peanutNamespace' Uri='http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'/&gt;"
             XmlInputPath=".\Parameters.xml" 
             Query="/parameters/setParameter[@name='LineNumber1']/@value">
            <Output TaskParameter="Result" PropertyName="PeekedSingle" />
        </XmlPeek>      

        <Message Text="PeekedSingle = $(PeekedSingle)   "/>
    </Target>   




    <Target Name="WriteXmlPeekValue"  Condition=" '$(PeekedSingle)' != '' ">
        <XmlPoke Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='msb' Uri='http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'/&gt;"
    XmlInputPath=".\Parameters.xml"
            Query="/parameters/setParameter[@name='LineNumber2']/@value"
    Value="$(PeekedSingle)" />
    </Target>   




</Project>
```

MyBatFile.bat (contents below)

```
set msBuildDir=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

call %msBuildDir%\msbuild /target:AllTargetsWrapped "MyMsbuildDef.proj" /p:Configuration=Debug;FavoriteFood=Popeyes /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=ZZZZZAllTargetsWrapped.log

set msBuildDir=
```

Comment: Thank you @granadaCoder for the sample code. you have the parameters defined and values are assigned to them before the build is triggered, But in my case the value is assigned at run-time(during build) and when I used your code I got parameter value as "". is there any workaround for this case.

Comment: If you pass them in as arguments to a command line, how are they generated?  So you would XmlWritePeekValue to a file...~then call the sub-task passing in the xml file name.  Then in that file, read out the values.  One process will create the variables-values in the xml, another process will real-the-variables.